# Share angular cli result over multiple azure pipeline jobs

Tags: angular-cli, azure-pipelines

How do I share my angular cli across steps?
Currently I put almost everything except in one big step in order to share the result of `npm ci` over all the tasks. This makes it complicated to define conditions and task parallelization.

I'm trying to set up an azure pipeline that does the following in separate steps

- prepares environment (get source, installs angular cli)
- validates (npm run lint, npm run test, publish test results)
- creates artifacts (build demo and prod binaries, zip them, publish them as artifacts)
- release to demo environments
- release to prod environments

Some of the steps are conditional on the trigger or the master/feature branch and some of the steps could run in parallel. Splitting them in steps triggers completely new agents that don't have the result of my previous tasks anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no default way to share a task result. For some tasks, like `installs angular cli`, you have to install it on each new agent, unless you use self-hosted agent. For tasks, like `publish test results`, if you want to reuse the result, you need to publish the result to a public location.

I'd like to suggest you use [task group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/task-groups?view=azure-devops). A task group allows you to encapsulate a sequence of tasks, already defined in a build or a release pipeline, into a single reusable task that can be added to a build or release pipeline, just like any other task. With task group, you don't have to add so many tasks in your pipeline.

Task groups are not supported in YAML pipelines. Instead, in that case you can use templates. See [YAML schema reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema#step-templates).

Comment: Re-executing npm install on every instance is just too time-consuming to be a feasible option. So this is not a solution, but it is an answer :)